# is FIQ (fast interrupt request) supported on armv7

Tags: linux-device-driver, armv7, cortex-a

Is the FIQ interrupt supported on armv7 architectures?  It looks like perhaps it's a deprecated interface, and there is not much documentation I can see on it.

Specifically, I'd like to service the SSI interrupt on the i.MX6 with an FIQ handler.  the mx6 is a multi-core cortex-a9 (armv7 architecture)

If FIQ is not supported any more in the arm architecture, is there any other means of very fast and low latency interrupt servicing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the ARM spec [Spec Doc for the Cortex A9](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0388f/DDI0388F_cortex_a9_r2p2_trm.pdf) if you have a look at page 175 (Appendix A.3) you'll see there's the ability to turn FIQs on and off.